# convert double to GLfloat in Haskell

Tags: opengl, haskell, double, floating-point-conversion

I want to convert a Double to a GLfloat.
I want to use it for comparations.

```
xM <- newIORef 0.0
zM <- newIORef 0.0
mobs <- newIORef []
mapM_ (\x -> colision x xM) mobs
```

mobs is fulled with a method.

```
colision mob xC = do
  xcama <- get xC
  --zcama <- get zC
  let menor = mob!!0
  let mayor = mob!!7
  --if xm>= xmin && xm <= xmax && zm >= zmin && zm <= zmax  then renderText (1, (-1.4)) $ "Dead"
  --else renderText (1, (-1.4)) $ "Warning..."
  renderText (1, (-1.4)) $ "Warning..."
```

When I try to compile it show me this error:

"Couldn't match type 'Foreign.C.Types.CDouble' with 'Foreign.C.Types.CFloat'
Expected type :GLfloat

Actual type: GLdouble

-----Solution:------

I use this code:

```
import GHC.Float
  d2f = realToFrac :: GLdouble -> GLfloat
```

Comment: You don't need that `import GHC.Float`, as `realToFrac` is a standard Haskell function reexported from the `Prelude`.

Answer (score 9):

The general function to use to convert between different floating point types (and some others, such as `Rational`) is `realToFrac`.

Answer (score 0):

Faster:

```
   import Unsafe.Coerce(unsafeCoerce)
   import GHC.Float(double2Float)
   doubleToGF = unsafeCoerce . double2Float :: Double -> GLfloat
```

I've been wishing for a way to make this less "unsafe" with Data.Coerce. Hasn't panned out as of yet

Comment: I have not looked it up in source sode, but theoretically it is not faster, because realToFrac is always rewritten for such primitive types at compile time using rewrite rules.